# Questions on the basics of database design

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm playing around with Sqlite3 in an attempt to get a handle on this SQL stuff. I've got a few questions on the topic.

Is there a basic structure that databases follow? I'm curious if I would model my database as though it were along the lines of a giant dictionary.

#### The problem I was thinking about:

If I wanted to have a program that could pull up the zip code or other general info for any city, I was thinking of a nested table kind of structure. Namely:

```
Countries Table:
+----+--------+--------+---------+
| US | Canada | Mexico |  Etc... |
+----+--------+--------+---------+
  |
  |
  |
  |
  | States Table:
  +---------+----------+---------+--------+
  | Alabama | Arkansas | Georgia | Etc... |
  +---------+----------+---------+--------+
                  |
                  |
                  |
                  |
                  | Cities Table:
                +-----------+---------+--------+---------+
                | Alexander | Bauxite | Benton | Etc ... |
                +-----------+---------+--------+---------+
                                           |
                                           |
                     +-----+------------+---------+------+--------------------+                    
                     | Key | population | zipcode | size | other random stuff |
                     +-----+------------+---------+------+--------------------+
```

But is that too much nesting..? Is that a bad design? The tip top stuff, the `countries` table doesn't really do much, and I kind of had it in my head that you were supposed to be able to do really complex things easily with a database. If I went with my design, it seems like I'd be looping over a bunch of stuff before I finally got to what I wanted. So, I'm just curious if I'm going about this entire thing incorrectly.

Does anyone know of a good primer on the basics of using a database?

Comment: I think you are on the right track here.  If I were building a database to store detailed address information, it would certainly include a Country and State table and possibly a City table as well (if that was practical).

Comment: Yes, your database design will follow this _general_ setup.  You have to be careful about international stuff for addresses, though; not all countries have 'states', the have 'provinces' (or something else equally similar).  In the US, I'm not sure that's the _exact_ relationship between state/zipcode (zipcodes are assigned based on population density, so it might end up covering _two_ small cities or something, instead of just multiple zipcodes per city).  But yeah, in general things end up looking like this.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Also, there are cases where cities, in USPS terms, overlap. Any Hollywood, CA zipcode is also a Los Angeles, CA zipcode, because what the USPS refers to as Hollywood isn't a real governmental entity, it's a part of LA. (And Chatsworth, CA is even worse—it's not a real governmental entity either, and part of it is part of LA, part is part of unincorporated LA County, and part is part of Ventura County…)

Comment: People who design databases the first time often think "that's too much nesting" when they've got it right. You'd never write an OO model with that much nesting. But an ER model is a different thing, and with an RDBMS, you can recover most of the benefits of the flatter model without losing the benefits of the deeper model, so the tradeoff is entirely different. (Of course as with code, you do need to profile and optimize. Sometimes going deep has a cost that can't be fully recovered with appropriate indices and views, in which case you have to denormalize. But don't do that prematurely.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational Databases are based on the [Entity-Relationship Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Further_reading). If you want to grasp the concept behind RDBSMs, consider familiarizing with that theory first. Specifically relational schemes (tables, columns,relationships through foreign keys, ...) are an (or the) application of the ERM.

Another keyword to search for is `Normalization`. There are different "grades" of normalization and rules to transform from one grade to another, that topic is directly related to your question about the table structure. A general answer is, it depends. In general Normalization helps keeping data consistent - but a fully normalized table structure may incur a performance penalty (e.g. many joins for often used queries).

I would suggest to first go with a stricter normalization and then check the performance. Selective denormalization **may** then help upping the performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is many normal forms (1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF...). Higher form = better granularity (not much redundancies, better relationships...).

May be a little detail. You have countries and states. But imho US is specific case in the world (not many others similar cases exist). May be tables States, Cities are enough (+ Continents).

And design relies on purpose (in some cases lower NF should be more efficient, depends up to many factors - records count, purpose etc.). You have to ask few questions. What is purpose of this database? Is table Cities enough, or i want to use villages too, so it should be table Municipalities? Etc. But your design is almost good ;)

Comment: The US is hardly unique in having states or equivalents—Canada, Mexico, Australia, Germany… However, you're right that there are multiple ways to break things down. It might be better to actually build a generic 3-level structure, where for each country you keep track of the name of levels 2 and 3… or even a tree structure.

Comment: Ok, Germany, Russia and others are also federative / federal countries. May be it seems to be (just for me?) not so obvious as in case of USA.

Comment: Equo, that kind of proves the point—neither you nor I nor the OP is likely to know off the top of our heads how all of the world's countries are actually divided… (And it's even more complicated than just federations vs. unitary states. What do you call Catalonia, for example, or Northern Ireland?) Which means either: borrow someone else's model, design something generic that can handle anything reasonable, or do a bunch of research. (And I'd put those in rough order from most to least desirable, for most projects.)

Comment: yes, there are more government systems. So the problem is more complex than we can think (or we just know it). And as you wrote the design relies just on purpose of DB. For some geographic DB it should be table Countries with all countries. For some politician DB it should be table Governement_system and than Countries with ID to system etc. Ok, i consider it close :)